# Receiving data from API in console log but can't able to show them on the web page

Tags: reactjs, rest, axios

## I'm fetching product details by using REST API and AXIOS I'm receiving the data in my console log but can't able to show the data in the single product page where i want to show

## please help me to solve this error

## this is my single product page

```
import { Add, Remove } from '@mui/icons-material';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Announcement from '../components/Announcement';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';
import Navbar from '../components/navbar';
import Newsletter from '../components/Newsletter';
import { mobile } from '../Responsive';
import { publicRequest } from '../requestMethods';
// import { addProduct } from '../redux/cartRedux';
// import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';



const Container = styled.div``;
const Wrapper = styled.div`
    padding: 50px;
    display: flex;
    ${mobile({padding: "10px", flexDirection:"column"})}
`;
const ImgContainer = styled.div`
    flex: 1;
`;
const Image = styled.img`
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    ${mobile({height: "40vh"})}
`;
const InfoContainer = styled.div`
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0 50px;
    ${mobile({padding: "10px"})}
`;
const Title = styled.h1`
    font-weight: 200;
`;
const Desc = styled.p`
    margin: 20px 0;
`;
const Price = styled.span`
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 100;
`;

const FilterContainer = styled.div`
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 30px 0;
    ${mobile({width: "100%"})}
`;
const Filter = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
`;
const FilterTitle = styled.span`
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 20;
`;
const FilterColor = styled.div`
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: ${props=>props.color};
    margin: 0 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
`;
const FilterSize = styled.select`
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding: 5px;

`;
const FilterSizeOption = styled.option``;

const AddContainer = styled.div`
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    ${mobile({width: "100%"})}
`;

const AmountContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 700;
`;
const Amount = styled.span`
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid teal;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin:  0 5px;
`;
const Button = styled.button`
    padding: 15px;
    border: 2px solid teal;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 500;

    &:hover{
        background-color: #f8f4f4;
    }
`;

const Product = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const id = location.pathname.split("/")[2];
    const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const getProduct = async () => {
        try {
          const res = await publicRequest.get("/products/find/" + id);
          setProduct(res.data);
          console.log(res);
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
      };
      getProduct();
    }, [id]);

    
  return (
    <Container>
        <Navbar/>
        <Announcement/>
        <Wrapper>
            <ImgContainer>
                <Image src= {product.img} />
            </ImgContainer>
            <InfoContainer>
                <Title>{product.title}
                </Title>
                <Desc>{product.desc}</Desc>
                <Price>{product.price}</Price>
                <FilterContainer>
                    <Filter>
                        <FilterTitle>Color</FilterTitle>
                        <FilterColor color="black" />
                        <FilterColor color="darkblue"/>
                        <FilterColor color="gray"/>
                    </Filter>
                    <Filter>
                        <FilterTitle>Size</FilterTitle>
                        <FilterSize>
                            <FilterSizeOption>XS</FilterSizeOption>
                            <FilterSizeOption>S</FilterSizeOption>
                            <FilterSizeOption>M</FilterSizeOption>
                            <FilterSizeOption>L</FilterSizeOption>
                            <FilterSizeOption>XL</FilterSizeOption>
                            <FilterSizeOption>XXL</FilterSizeOption>
                        </FilterSize>
                    </Filter>
                </FilterContainer>
                <AddContainer>
                    <AmountContainer>
                        <Remove/>
                        <Amount>1</Amount>
                        <Add/>
                    </AmountContainer>
                    <Button>Add to cart</Button>
                </AddContainer>
            </InfoContainer>
        </Wrapper>
        <Newsletter/>
        <Footer/>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Product
```

## and this is my AXIOS request method

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/";
const TOKEN = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYzZjdiNTk5OTliYjNkMzI2MGU4ZGY0NSIsImlzQWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTY3ODQzNzI5NywiZXhwIjoxNjc4Njk2NDk3fQ.4ncPTwHxOPKHxjK3m8LgmN04NzdfBWtvKiLoce6b20Q";


export const publicRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
});


export const userRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    header: {token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`}
})
```

[This is my console log where i received the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovIax.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `setProduct(res.data);` to `setProduct(res.data.product);`

From your screenshot of the data you received, the structure is as following

```json
{
  "data": {
    "product": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

However, the `setProduct` function you called in the `useEffect` is assigning the entire payload of `data` to the `product` variable which is incorrect.

Comment: I get it now Thank you even  i solved the error now

Answer (score 0):

following code might help you :

```
useEffect(() => {
      const getProduct = async () => {
        try {
          const res = await publicRequest.get("/products/find/" + id);
          setProduct(res?.data?.product?.categories);
          console.log(res);
        } catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
      };
      getProduct();
    }, [id]);
```

another changes below :

```
product?.map((singleproduct)=>(
<ImgContainer>
                <Image src= {singleproduct.img} />
            </ImgContainer>
            <InfoContainer>
                <Title>{singleproduct.title}
                </Title>
                <Desc>{singleproduct.desc}</Desc>
                <Price>{singleproduct.price}</Price>
                <FilterContainer>
                    <Filter>
                        <FilterTitle>Color</FilterTitle>
                        <FilterColor color="black" />
                        <FilterColor color="darkblue"/>
                        <FilterColor color="gray"/>
                    </Filter>
                    <Filter>
                        <FilterTitle>Size</FilterTitle>
                        <FilterSize>
                            <FilterSizeOption>XS</FilterSizeOption>
                            <FilterSizeOption>S</FilterSizeOption>
                            <FilterSizeOption>M</FilterSizeOption>
                            <FilterSizeOption>L</FilterSizeOption>
                            <FilterSizeOption>XL</FilterSizeOption>
                            <FilterSizeOption>XXL</FilterSizeOption>
                        </FilterSize>
                    </Filter>
                </FilterContainer>
                <AddContainer>
                    <AmountContainer>
                        <Remove/>
                        <Amount>1</Amount>
                        <Add/>
                    </AmountContainer>
                    <Button>Add to cart</Button>
                </AddContainer>
            </InfoContainer>)
```

Comment: Thank you Asma for your time and efforts